# Apache Syncope REST API: Set password on user creation

Tags: rest, apache-syncope

Apache Syncope 2.0.0-M2

I use Syncope REST API to create a user. It is created successfully, except for the password, which remains `null`.

Does anyone know how to get password defined?

Here is the command:

```
$ curl -X POST -u admin:password -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/tmp/newuser.json http://192.168.99.100:8080/syncope/rest/users
```

Request body (/tmp/newuser.json):

```
{"password":"1qaz2wsx","@class":"org.apache.syncope.common.lib.to.UserTO","realm":"/","type":"USER","username":"test1467220729151"}
```

Successful user creation response (with `"password":null`):

```
{"any":{"@class":"org.apache.syncope.common.lib.to.UserTO","creator":"admin","creationDate":"2016-06-29T17:26:38.115+0000","lastModifier":"admin","lastChangeDate":"2016-06-29T17:26:38.115+0000","key":125,"type":"USER","realm":"/","status":"active","password":null,"token":null,"tokenExpireTime":null,"username":"test1467220729151",...}
```

I tried `?storePassword=true` URI parameter, but same result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that I use custom Apache Syncope, which alters the response by `null`-ing the `password` field.
The password itself is set correctly and can be used for authentication.